# What is the cyclic subgroup generated by $9$ in $U(28)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$U(28)=\{1,3,5,9,11,13,15,17,19,23,25,27\}$

So $\langle 9\rangle = \{1,9,25\}$, correct?

Why is this the case? How is it generating $25$? Wouldn't $27$ be the last element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see.

Start with $9$. As $9 \cdot 9 = 81 \equiv -3 \equiv 25 \bmod 28$, we see that the next element in the cycle is $25$.

As $9 \cdot 25 \equiv 9 \cdot -3 = -27 \equiv 1 \bmod 28$, the next element in the cycle is $1$. And since we've gotten $1$, this means that $9$ is of order $3$, and generates the group $\{ 1, 9 ,25 \}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing addition instead of multiplication

Answer (score 1):

$U(28)$ is a group under multiplication so:

$9$

$81\equiv 25 \mod{28}$

$9^3=729 \equiv 1 \mod{28}$

are all the distinct elements you get as powers of 9.

So $\langle 9\rangle = \{1,9,25\}$

Comment: Aha! Under multiplication. I was doing addition. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently $25$ will belong to $\langle 9\rangle$, since $25\cdot 9 = 225 = 28\cdot 8 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{28}$. Hence, $\operatorname{inv}(9) = 25$, so $25$ belongs to $\langle 9\rangle$, since for all $a$ in a group $G$, $\operatorname{inv}(a)$ belongs to $\langle a\rangle$.